# Accidentally deleted boot etc, lib and bin folders (Ubuntu 14.04), need help in restoring them, if possible

Tags: 14.04, boot, live-usb, delete, restore

Was trying to delete folders from a boot-able Linux kernel on a flash drive and accidentally deleted the folders in the Linux installation on my laptop. Is there a way to recover/ restore the files and folders without actually having to go through a complete re-installation.

The folders deleted were `/bin` `/boot` `/dev` `/etc` and `/lib`. I am not sure as to what extent the damage is to the system and know that these are critical to the system. I hope there is a way to restore them back.
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: The easiest and least painful way is, re-install the system.

Comment: Yes @A.B. thats what I ended up doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unlikely that you system is usable after removing the `/lib` directory, since this contains the runtime linker (e.g., `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.21.so`).

Without this file you will not be able to run any dynamically linked binaries (which, in general, means everything).

Any attempt to restore these directories is probably going to be complex and error prone; you are far better off simply starting from scratch.  If you have data on the system that needs to be preserved, you can boot from a live CD and copy it onto another destination (e.g., a USB thumb drive or another host on your network).

If you really wanted to try to restore things, the process would probably look something like:

- Boot from a live CD
- Copy over enough files to get `apt` working (this will probably include select contents of `/lib` as well as all of `/etc/apt`)
- `chroot` into your broken environment and use `apt-get` to reinstall all your packages, possibly with a command line like `apt-get --reinstall install $(dpkg --get-selections | awk '{print $1}')`

But even if that works, it probably won't be an exact replica of what you had before.

Comment: Thank you for the help. The process of restoring was cumbersome and frankly not worth the effort, I just backed up the data by booting from a live CD and re-installed from scratch.